# scala existence type of type class

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, typeclass

I want to define a function like this

`def showList(items: Seq[_ : Show]) = {...}`
type parameter of `Seq` is any type that has an context bound `Show`

Thus I could call `showList(Seq(1, "abc"))`.

How should declare the method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def showList[A: Show](items: Seq[A]) = { ... }
```

or more explicitly (with the advantage of having the type class instance directly available)

```
def showList[A](items: Seq[A])(implicit ev: Show[A]) = { ... }
```

For the specific case, since scala collections are monomorphic, you'll need a `Show[Any]` instance.

Comment: @jilen what's the specific error? Do you have an instance of `Show` for both `Int` and `String` in scope?

Comment: @jilen also `'abc'` is not valid scala. Do you mean `"abc"`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "abc", because `Seq(1, "abc")` is infered to 'Seq[Any]'

Comment: @jilen since scala collections are monomorphic you'll need an instance of `Show[Any]` in scope

Comment: I hoped that existence type would help, but seems wrong